# Why does GitHub continue to push with a different version of the one used in Pipfile?

Tags: github

Whenever I push to the platform I have a Python version error:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 31708, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23964/23964), done.
Writing objects: 100% (31708/31708), 293.38 MiB | 1.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 31708 (delta 7100), reused 31670 (delta 7076)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using python-3.5.2, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.5.2
```

While I have the following `Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"

[packages]
requests = { extras = ['socks'] }

[requires]
python_full_version = "3.6.5"
```

and that I did a `pipenv lock`

Here is my version of Python:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.5
```

Why does GitHub continue to push with a different version of the one used in Pipfile?

Comment: Did you push `Pipfile.lock`  after doing `pipenv lock`?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence Yes